# How to detect current location in kendo UI?

Tags: jquery-ui, mvvm, kendo-ui

how to detect user location in kendo ui ? please provide some live snippets

Comment: Welcome to SO, where Developers Learn, Share, & Build Careers! Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow — we expect questions here to relate to specific programming problems — but we will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us [what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. This will also help us answer your question better

Answer (score 0):

here is my solution

```
<script>
    $.get("http://ipinfo.io", function (response) 
        {
            $("#address").html("Location: " + response.city + ", " + response.region);
        }, 
  "jsonp");
</script>
```